# Join en sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, join, flask, sqlalchemy

Estoy tratando de pasar una consulta que tengo hecha -y ya probé que funciona en SQL- a SQLAlchemy en python usando Flask.

Esta es la query en SQL:

```
select Reclamo.IdReclamo from
Reclamo,ServicioAsignacion,ReclamoServicioAsignacionAfectado where
ServicioAsignacion.IdServicioAsignacion=ReclamoServicioAsignacionAfectado.idServicioAsignacion 
and Reclamo.IdReclamo=ReclamoServicioAsignacionAfectado.idReclamo 
and Reclamo.masivo=1 and Reclamo.estado<>'Solucionado' 
and ServicioAsignacion.IdServicioAsignacion=232750
```

Estas son mis tablas en el `model.py`:

```
class reclamo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Reclamo'
    idreclamo = db.Column('IdReclamo', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    estado = db.Column('estado', db.String(255))
    idcliente = db.Column('idCliente', db.Integer,
                          db.ForeignKey('Cliente.IdCliente'))
    cliente = db.relationship('cliente', backref='reclamo')
    idservicioasignacion = db.Column('idServicioAsignacion', db.Integer) 
    reclamoservicioasignacionafectado = db.relationship('reclamoservicioasignacionafectado', backref ='reclamo', lazy='dynamic')
    masivo = db.Column('masivo', db.Integer)

class servicioasignacion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ServicioAsignacion'
    idservicioasignacion = db.Column('IdServicioAsignacion', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    idcliente = db.Column('idCliente', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Cliente.IdCliente'))
    cliente = db.relationship('cliente', backref = 'servicioasignacion')

class reclamoservicioasignacionafectado(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ReclamoServicioAsignacionAfectado'
    idreclamoservicioasignacionafectado = db.Column('idReclamoServicioAsignacionAfectado', db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    idreclamo = db.Column('idReclamo', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Reclamo.IdReclamo'))
    idservicioasignacion = db.Column('idServicioAsignacion', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ServicioAsignacion.IdServicioAsignacion'))
    servicioasignacion = db.relationship('servicioasignacion', backref= 'reclamoservicioasignacionafectado')
    idcliente = db.Column('idCliente', db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('Cliente.IdCliente'))
    cliente  = db.relationship('cliente', backref = 'reclamoservicioasignacionafectado')
```

Y este es la query que estoy intentando, pero me tira un error (`TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`):

```
@app.route('/verificarincidencia/<idservice>', methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def verificarincidencia_get(idservice):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        checkincidencia = reclamo.query(reclamo,servicioasignacion,reclamoservicioasignacionafectado).join(servicioasignacion).join(reclamoservicioasignacionafectado).filter(servicioasignacion.idservicioasignacion==reclamoservicioasignacionafectado.idservicioasignacion).filter(reclamo.idreclamo==reclamoservicioasignacionafectado.idreclamo).filter(reclamo.masivo==1).filter(reclamo.estado!='Solucionado').filter(servicioasignacion.idservicioasignacion==idservice).all()
        return jsonify( {'reclamo': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkincidencia] })
```

Desde ya muchísimas gracias (si llego a tener la solución lo publico). Estoy seguro que no estoy entendiendo bien el tema de armar un join en SQLAlchemy pero quizás alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Porque pasas reclamo como parámetro?

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo la implementación de SQLAlchemy y Flask-SQLAlchemy. Confirmarme si estás usando dicho middleware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pondré un ejemplo usando una estructura bien sencilla. Luego sera tu tarea aplicar los mismos conceptos a tus necesidades.

Teniendo unas entidades con la siguiente estructura relacional.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La manera de definirlos en SQLAlchemy usando el [Systema Declarativo](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html) pero con los añadidos de [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/) seria así:

```
class Cliente(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(200))  # nombre del cliente

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Cliente nombre='%s'>" % (self.nombre)


class Servicio(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(200))  # nombre del servicio

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Servicio nombre='%s'>" % (self.nombre)


class Estado(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(200))  # nombre del servicio

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Estado nombre='%s'>" % (self.nombre)
```

Para ahorrar espacio, no definí en ninguna clase la propiedad `__tablename__`. Flask-SQLAlchemy lo setea automaticamente con el nombre
de la clase en minusculas. Asi, Cliente pasara a ser `__tablename__ = 'cliente'`.

Por último la clase con la que se relacionan las demas entidades.

```
class Reclamo(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cliente_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cliente.id'))
    servicio_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('servicio.id'))
    estado_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('estado.id'))

    # Aqui pasamos el nombre de las clases y no el nombre de la tabla
    servicio = db.relationship('Servicio')
    cliente = db.relationship('Cliente')
    estado = db.relationship('Estado')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Reclamo id='%s'>" % (self.id)
```

## Las consultas

Para enviar un join que incluya todas las tablas y nos devuelva todos los registros de la entidad `Reclamo`, lo harías así:

Fijense que estamos usando el metodo **`query`** de la sesión y no de la tabla  Reclamo. Pasamos todas las tablas que queramos que sean parte del `SELECT` y luego en el metodo **`join`** las reclacion sobre las que queremos hacer el
`JOIN`.

```
db.session.query(Reclamo, Servicio, Cliente, Estado).\
    join(Reclamo.servicio, Reclamo.cliente, Reclamo.estado).\
    all()
```

Si queremos aplicar una clausula `WHERE` agregamos un filtro usando **`filter`**:

```
db.session.query(Reclamo, Servicio, Cliente, Estado).\
    join(Reclamo.servicio, Reclamo.cliente, Reclamo.estado).\
    filter(Estado.id == 1).\
    all()
```

Lo de arriba devolverá solo los reclamos que tengan como `id` igual a 1. Podemos aplicar tantos filtros queramos. Lo que equivale a agregar el operador `AND` luego de `WHERE`.

## Resultado devuelto

En todos los casos se devuelve una lista de tuplas, y dichas tuplas conienen las instancias de las clases (tablas) pasadas al metodo **`query`**. Suponiendo que tenemos ya datos en la base de datos, si imprimimos en la consola deberia aparecer:

```
[(<Reclamo id='1'>, <Servicio nombre='Internet'>, <Estado nombre='abierto'>, <Cliente nombre='Maria'>),
 (<Reclamo id='2'>, <Servicio nombre='Internet'>, <Estado nombre='abierto'>, <Cliente nombre='Mirta'>)]
```

## Visualizar el código SQL precompilado en consola:

Tenemos que habilitar el modo echo del engine utilizado en la conccion:

```
# de forma directa
db.engine.echo = True

# agregando la configuración en Flask
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
```

## Nota

Agregar todas las posibilidades que ofrece SQLAlchemy a la hora de hacer consultas alargaría mucho esta respuesta. Arriba solo puse las maneras basicas de enviar peticiones usando `JOIN` a la base de datos.

Comment: Hola miso, muchísimas gracias, con lo que explicaste me sirvió para entender un poco mas y creo haberlo solucionado, no del todo aun pero tengo fe! . Me falta fijar algunos conceptos respecto SQLAlchemy y Flask. Pero muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Saludos!

Comment: Si tenés nuevas dudas, tenés que crear una nueva pregunta. Si está te derivó marca como correcta.

Comment: Si, ya está, como la marco como correcta? O eso lo tenes que hacer vos? Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: En el lado izquierdo de mi respuesta, tiene que aparecer un símbolo de check en gris, tenés que darle click y ponerlo en verde.

Comment: Hola Miso. Muchísimas gracias. Tu respuesta es verdaderamente útil y clara